# PowerShell Copy file on same server over network

Tags: powershell

I got a piece of script here but is still not working as i want :) and i cannot see the mistake :( , in this moment $Computer is getting me only the last hostname that is in file "servers.txt" , i want it to copy the file whoami.txt from one folder to another on each server that is in the "servers.txt" file. any ideas ? Thank you in advance !

```
$Servers = "C:\test\Servers.txt"
$Source = "\\$Computer\C$\test\whoami.txt"
$Destination = "\\$Computer\C$\Test2"
$ComputerName = Get-Content $Servers foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName)       {Copy-Item $Source -Destination $Destination}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
Get-Content "C:\test\Servers.txt" | ForEach-Object {
  Copy-Item "\\$_\C$\test\whoami.txt" "\\$_\C$\Test2" -WhatIf
}
```

Remove `-WhatIf` to ensure the command does what you want.